# Facebook wall post code not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Can somebody please tell me why the following code is not giving me the form to post message on wall? It just redirects to the $homeurl !

CONFIG.SYS

```
<?php
require_once("facebook/src/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK

######### edit details ##########
$appId = '****************************'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = '**********************************'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'http://www.landshoppe.com/process.php';  //return url (url to script)
$homeurl = 'http://www.landshoppe.com/';  //return to home

$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';  //Required facebook permissions

##################################

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new facebook(array( 'appId'  => $appId, 'secret' => $appSecret));

$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

My AppId and AppSecret are correct. Still, $fbuser does not seem to connect. Echoing $fbuser gives 0. And the index.php facebook post form redirects to home url since $fbuser does not connect I presume.. what should be the problem ?

Comment: I don’t see you logging the user in to your app anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add login handling with `getLoginUrl` otherwise if the user has not logged into your application, `user` will always be zero